# How do you change the table_schema when the current table_schema is null?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I somehow managed to create a table in a database with a null table schema.
I can't query the table since it has no owner, and altering the table doesn't work for the same reason.

I would alter the table using:

```
ALTER SCHEMA null TRANSFER dbo.SubscriptionAnswerMR
```

But that doesn't work.

The information_schema.tables looks like this:

```
TABLE_CATALOG   TABLE_SCHEMA    TABLE_NAME              TABLE_TYPE
q_Profiles              NULL    SubscriptionAnswerMR    BASE TABLE
```

So my question is: How do I change q_Profiles' table_schema?

SQL Server 2000 (*edit*)
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to verify that your table is fine by seeing the result of the following query:

```
SELECT u.name
  FROM q_Profiles..sysobjects AS o
  INNER JOIN q_Profiles..sysusers AS u
  ON o.uid = u.uid
  WHERE o.name = 'SubscriptionAnswerMR';
```

This should be `dbo` unless someone explicitly created them with a different owner or used [`sp_changeobjectowner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259618%28SQL.80%29.aspx). Which you can use if you find that sysobjects also has the wrong answer:

```
EXEC sp_changeobjectowner 'SubscriptionAnswerMR', 'dbo';
```

`ALTER SCHEMA` is not valid here because it was introduced in SQL Server 2005. Though it would be useful for you to describe what "doesn't work" means.

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is a horribly unreliable set of views as @Pondlife points out. Also see the following, which doesn't help you much in SQL Server 2000, but should help going forward:

- [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)

Also as a side note you seem to be confused about tables and database. `TABLE_CATALOG` is the database, not the table.

Answer (score 1):

Did you note this comment in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224%28v=sql.100%29)?

> Do not use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views to determine the schema of an
>   object. The only reliable way to find the schema of a object is to
>   query the sys.objects catalog view or use the OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME
>   function.

Comment: Agree 100%. Except OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME() is not valid in SQL Server 2000, nor is sysobjects. Your documentation is too new! :-)

Comment: Absolutely right, although since the OP tagged his question as SQL 2008 (since updated) it's not surprising that I referred him to that documentation :-)